# how to loop through a four level json array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, dynamic

Four level JSON data

```
{
"Asia": [
    {
        "continentCode": "GT113",
        "regionList": [
            {
                "regionName": "Eastern Asia",
                "regionCode": "GR128",
                "Countrylist": [
                    {
                        "countryName": "China",
                        "countryCode": "GC302",
                        "subCountryList": [
                            {
                                "subCountryName": "Southern China",
                                "subCountryCode": "GR206"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "countryName": "Hong Kong",
                        "countryCode": "GC303"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "regionName": "Southern Asia",
                "regionCode": "GR134",
                "Countrylist": [
                    {
                        "countryName": "India",
                        "countryCode": "GC304"
                    },
                    {
                        "countryName": "Pakistan",
                        "countryCode": "GC309"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I have fetched the data upto 3 level and dispalyed upto 2 level. But cant able to fetch the 4th level data and display the 3rd and 4th level of data.

```js
$.each(json, function (i1, object) {
   alert(i1);
   $.each(object, function (i2, continent) {
    $.each(continent.regionList, function (i3, region) {
     alert(region.regionName);
     $.each(region.Countrylist, function (i4, country) {
      alert(country.countryName);
      if (!$("ul." + i1).is("*")) {
       $("<ul />", {
         "class": i1,
         "html": "<li>" + region.regionName + "</li>"
       }).appendTo("div").before('<b class=' + i1 + ' ><a name="' + i1 + '" >' + i1 + '</a></b>');
      }else{
       $("b." + i1).each(function() {
        var text = this.textContent || this.innerText;
        if (text === i1) {
         $(this).next("ul").append("<li>" + region.regionName + "</li>");
        }
       });
      }
      
      /* $.each(country.subCountryList, function (i5, subCountry) {
       alert(subCountry.subCountryName);
      }); */
     });
    });
   });
  });
 })
```

```html
<div>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

How to fetch the others to display as below

- **Asia**
- **Eastern Asia**
- China -
- Southern China
- Hongkong
- **Southern Asia**

Comment: `val` is an array of regions. So you could just to `$.each(val, function(i, region) { ... })`, and so on.... What exactly is the issue? Do you not know how to iterate over arrays or how to access an array element or object property?

Comment: Then I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide, which explains the basics of arrays and objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, using some code of @dimitar:

```js
var json = {
  "Asia": [{
    "continentCode": "GT113",
    "regionList": [{
      "regionName": "Eastern Asia",
      "regionCode": "GR128",
      "Countrylist": [{
        "countryName": "China",
        "countryCode": "GC302",
        "subCountryList": [{
          "subCountryName": "Northern China",
          "subCountryCode": "GR207"
        }, {
          "subCountryName": "Southern China",
          "subCountryCode": "GR206"
        }]
      }, {
        "countryName": "Hong Kong",
        "countryCode": "GC303"
      }]
    }, {
      "regionName": "Southern Asia",
      "regionCode": "GR134",
      "Countrylist": [{
        "countryName": "India",
        "countryCode": "GC304"
      }, {
        "countryName": "Pakistan",
        "countryCode": "GC309"
      }]
    }]
  }]
};

var html = '';
$.each(json, function(i1, object) {
  html += '<li><b>' + i1 + '</b>';
  $.each(object, function(i2, continent) {
    html += '<ul>';
    $.each(continent.regionList, function(i3, region) {
      html += '<li><b>' + region.regionName + '</b>';
      $.each(region.Countrylist, function(i4, country) {
        html += '<ul><li>' + country.countryName;
        if (country.subCountryList) {
          html += "<ul>";
          $.each(country.subCountryList, function(i5, subCountry) {
            html += '<li>' + subCountry.subCountryName + '</li>';
          });
          html += "</ul>";
        };
        html += '</li></ul>';
      });
      html += '</li>';
    });
    html += '</ul>';
  });
  html += '</li>';
});

$('#list').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

Comment: i am trying to select the node and child for the tree structure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30581983/how-to-find-and-check-all-dynamic-child-checkboxes-in-tree-using-jquery.

Comment: @bimacknyas, kindly see my answer to your post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30637592/2575725)

Comment: When i am trying to add more subcountries "subCountryList": [ {"subCountryName": "Southern China","subCountryCode": "GR206" },{"subCountryName": "Southern China","subCountryCode": "GR206"} ], all the subcountries are not coming under "ul" element. It is coming as separare "ul li". How can i append all the subcountries inside the "ul" element.

Comment: it still coming with separate "ul li" element inside the country level "li" element.How can i change the structure as "<li>China <ul><li>southern China</li><li>Northen China</li></ul></li>"

Answer (score 1):

You will want to loop through all of them and print out something on each level.

Here is an example, tweak it to your liking and style it.

```
$.each(json, function (i1, object) {
    console.log(i1);
    $.each(object, function (i2, continent) {
        $.each(continent.regionList, function (i3, region) {
            console.log(region.regionName);
            $.each(region.Countrylist, function (i4, country) {
                console.log(country.countryName);
                if(country.subCountryList){
                    $.each(country.subCountryList, function (i5, subCountry) {
                        console.log(subCountry.subCountryName);
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here json is your JSON you provided and we print out the list you wanted in the console.

Edited original code:

```
$.each(json, function (i1, object) {
    $("ul").append("<li><strong>"+i1+"</li></strong>");
    $.each(object, function (i2, continent) {
        $.each(continent.regionList, function (i3, region) {
            $("ul").append("<li><p><strong>"+region.regionName+"</li></p></strong>");
            $.each(region.Countrylist, function (i4, country) {
                $("ul").append("<li><p>"+country.countryName+"</li></p>");
                if(country.subCountryList){
                    $.each(country.subCountryList, function (i5, subCountry) {
                        $("ul").append("<li><p>"+subCountry.subCountryName+"</li></p>");
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Leave me a comment if there are still issues, I am not getting any.

Comment: I hadnt noticed that level. You will need to check if it exists, since it doesnt for all countries. I have edited my post with an example of how this can be done. Depending on how the rest of this JSON looks like you may want to add such checks everywhere, in case there are regions without countries for example.

Comment: Yes thats great, but not able display all the data. Please have a look to my code.

Comment: If I replace the commented part of your code with my IF check, it works fine.

Comment: I am able to see all the data trough console but i am not able to display the data dynamically like the above html  structure

Comment: I looked at your code and I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do there. I updated my second code snippet, it prints literally what you asked for.